# Swift - open the music app and play specific album

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

I'm having problems with finding out information or a documentation on how to open the music app with a specific album and playing it.

The closest I found right now is

```
        let url = URL(string: "music://")
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

I've tried a few combinations with the path and options but no luck, it always just opens the app and does nothing beyond that.

I initially thought this would open through the MPMediaPlayer but that just plays it in the app and is now what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the MPMusicPlayerController `systemMusicPlayer`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller

It *is* the Music app.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this... Thank you!

Comment: Note that it won't physically _switch_ to the Music app, though you can do that in the way you were already doing it if you really need to.

Comment: It actually does switch for me. Only thing is it doesn't prompt the view to the album, it just stays wherever I was previously browsing.

Comment: Oh well yeah, it switches because I left the old code there! So you are absolutely right